# How to avoid linker errors when defining method out-of-line in header

Tags: c++, linker

I'm trying to define a header-only library which gets included in multiple object-files. Everything works if I define all the class's methods in-line,

```
// lib.hpp
class Foo {
  void fn() { ... }
};
```

But a dependency loop with `class Bar` requires I define `Foo::fn` out of line.

```
// lib.hpp
class Foo {
  void fn();
}
class Bar { ... }
void Foo::fn() { ... }
```

And I am suddenly getting `multiple definitions of Foo::fn` (as expected).

My question is how to define the method out-of-line while making the visibility local to each object file (as it was when it was in-line). If this were a function, I would slap a `static` in front, but that seems to only further incense my compiler.

- I tried using `static`, no luck.
- I tried using `__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))`, no luck.
- This is not a duplicate of [How to avoid multiple definition linking error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654365/how-to-avoid-multiple-definition-linking-error), because that is a name-conflict (different names and different definitions), which can be resolved with a `namespace`. I have a "false" name conflict, because I want the names be "hidden" rather than both available under disambiguous identifiers.
- This is not a duplicate of [multiple definition error including c++ header file with inline code from multiple sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212006/multiple-definition-error-including-c-header-file-with-inline-code-from-multip) because my code *is* unique within one translation unit but *is not* between multiple object-files.

Comment: Function definitions in the header have to be inline. You need to add `inline` in front of them. (You don’t need it when defining them in the class body because they are implicitly inline there)

Comment: Also worth considering "What do I gain from separating the method implementations?" If you aren't placing them in a CPP file where they don't need to be compiled as often, all you're doing is adding extra work for yourself by separating. Is the extra work worth it?

Comment: @t.niese if make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.